# Failed to import { Match } from 'meteor/match';

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I tried to use `Match.ObjectIncluding` in angular2-meteor1.3.1 project.

Based on this file [meteor.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/tomitrescak/8366ce98f1857e202ea8), I can successful use

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
```

However, when I tried to use

```
import { Match } from 'meteor/match';
```

I got error:

```
/Users/hongbo-miao/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.z9fvfj++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Can't find npm module 'meteor/match'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
    at Object.Npm.require (/test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:195:17)
    at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime.js:413:18)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:98:16)
    at meteorInstall.collections.methods.ts (collections/methods.ts:2:1)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
    at /test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:905:1
    at /test/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/hongbo-miao/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.1.z9fvfj++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

How can I import Match correctly? Thanks

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, have you tried with `meteor/check`?

Comment: @Kyll wow, I got warning `Cannot find module 'meteor/check’.`, but it seems working. So maybe that Type definitions for Meteor 1.3 is wrong?

Comment: No idea whatsoever. I'm going to make some checks myself (pun maybe intended) and come back with an answer.

Comment: Using `import { Match } from 'meteor/check'` worked for me server-side and client-side, without any warning. This warning issue might need further investigation. I'm not sure if this question should be closed or not as "No repro" as per the [help/on-topic] since solving the issue was just changing a package name. Do you think this question holds value for future visitors, or should simply be closed or deleted? In the first case I can add an answer.

Comment: @Kyll yeah, I think it is an error for meteor.d.ts file, I commented it at bottom [here](https://gist.github.com/tomitrescak/8366ce98f1857e202ea8)

Comment: Might be yes, I read TypeScript as well as Swedish. As such, people of deh future are unlikely to encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the typings file is wrong. The new typings file is [here](https://github.com/barbatus/meteor-typings/blob/master/meteor/1.3/meteor.d.ts), which uses

```
'meteor/check'
```